# How to add required field blank field in serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I need to add that field should be added compulsory in serializers how to do that?

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SignUpSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')
```

I'm expecting some kind of validators to validate those fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use keyword args function to validate like

```
class SignUpSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')

    extra_kwargs = {
        'first_name':{'required':True, 'allow_blank':False},
        'last_name':{'required':True, 'allow_blank':False},
        'email':{'required':True, 'allow_blank':False}
    }
```

Comment: what can i do for password? i need min for 6 characters

Comment: you can add `'password':{'required':True, 'allow_blank':False, 'min_length':6`